# How to change a session value after a click event, so that a page refresh does not reset the session on Meteor

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

I am very close to having my app perform as I want, however there is one little issue I am having. I cant seem to get the Session.set to stay after a click event and the user reloads the page. I am basically trying to build a age gate for viewing a alcohol vendors site.

You can view the site [here](http://nt-dev.cf), when you click the link it hides the map, but when you refresh it comes back, I want it to hide the map after the initial click and after refresh, but the initial click is needed.

You can view my javaScript below

```
Template.homePage.helpers({
   // because the Session variable will most probably be undefined the first time
   data: function(){

         return !Session.get("enter");

   }
});

Template.homePage.events({
  'click a' : function(){
    alert("removeMap");
    Session.set("enter", false);
  }
});


Template.homePage.rendered = function(){
  Session.set("enter", true);
}
```

**

> JS Update

**

```
Template.homePage.helpers({
   // because the Session variable will most probably be undefined the first time
   data: function(){

         return !Session.get("enter");

   }
});

Template.homePage.events({
  'click a' : function(){
    alert("removeMap");
    Session.setPersistent("enter", false);
    console.log(Session.get("enter"));
  }
});



Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.setTemp("enter", true);
    console.log(Session.get("enter"));
});
```

and my template

```
<template name="homePage">



{{#if data}}

{{> postsList}}

{{ else }}

<h1>Choose a Province:</h1>

{{> map}}

<a href="#">Click Me</a>

{{/if}}



</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you asked is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371324/meteor-session-and-browser-refreshes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877554/sessions-in-meteor).

Also, you can use [this package](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session) if you want your session to be persistent

Comment: I have read through each question multiple times. I have installed this package, but I am still having issues making the session stay persistent after the click and after a refresh in that order, it still gets reset on page refresh, even though it is set as temp.I have updated my code above.

Comment: Why do you set this session as temp at startup? You said you want it to be persistent. Try something like `Session.setDefaultPersistent("enter",false)` and then just update it with `Session.update("enter",true)`. And if you want it to change from temp to persist you have to use method `Session.makePersistent(key)` and then change value, instead of `Session.setPersistent("enter", false)`

Comment: Sorry, I hate to ask could you show me a little more detailed. Where do I put Session.setDefaultPersistent("enter",false) if not in meteor.startup. Currently it returns true on console.log. I am not getting this, sorry.

Comment: `Template.homePage.helpers({
   // because the Session variable will most probably be undefined the first time
   data: function(){

         return !(Session.get("enter"));

   }
});

Template.homePage.events({
  'click a' : function(){
    alert("removeMap");
    Session.update("enter",true)
    console.log(Session.get("enter"));
  }
});



Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.setDefaultPersistent("enter",false)
    console.log(Session.get("enter"));
});`
I think this is the right approach, can't test it cause im not in home right now. P.S. Code blocks in comments suck

Comment: Thank you, my last comment didnt work and it wouldnt let me choose your answer because stack was having errors. I had to clear my cookies, so dumb. Thanks for all your help working great now.